# Como consigo hacer una linea al lado del texto?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Quiero lograr hacer una linea al lado del texto rollo asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se aplicar lo de hacer puntitos y tal con dashed pero ni poniendolo todo en d-flex, ni con inline block consigo que se ponga asi, al lado del texto.
Casi la conseguir cuadrar con los col pero no queda del todo bien, ya que uso hr y no le consigo aplicar los puntitos y cuadrarlo del todo

```css
hr {
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4 p-0 m-0">
  <span> corona bot 33cl </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 p-0 m-0">
  <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 p-0 m-0">
  4€
  </div>
  
  <div>
```

Comment: Mira a ver si esto te da ideas: https://jsfiddle.net/qy6o59mj/

Comment: siii justo. Muchas gracias

Comment: No cantes victoria... deberás ajustar los valores del svg en tu página para que al redimensionar no te genere una nueva linea de columna... el truco esta en ponerle un height alto para que no lo haga (aunque no entiendo el porque, pero asi veo que me funciona)... ya nos contaras si realmente te ha funcionado y como lo has implementado (ponlo en una respuesta cuando lo tengas)

Comment: valee probare lo del height para que haga responsive. Si lo consigo lo posteo como respuesta baia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que es asi si no me equivoco?

```css
.dotted {
  padding-top:0em;
  margin-top:0em;
  border-bottom: dashed 2px #000;
  height: 19px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 text-end">
      hola
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 dotted">
    </div>
   <div class="col-4 text-start">4€</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, o sea, lo que te faltaba era lo del text-end y text-start para que los textos queden pegados a las lineas, entiendo.  Saludos!